# Tcl: pass argument with square brackets to procedure

Tags: tcl

I want to pass a string argument to a tcl procedure, without interpreting the contents of brackets as a command, and without using \ to escape the brackets. For example:

```
proc resolve_signal_path {signal_path} {
    puts $signal_path
    # Replace [] with ():
    set signal_path [string map -nocase {"[" "(" "]" ")"} $signal_path]
    return $signal_path
}

puts [resolve_signal_path abc[0]]
```

This gives an "invalid command name "0"" error. How can I pass such arguments?
I tried single quotes '' around the argument to no avail.

UPDATE: In particular is there a way to handle this if the arguments is a list and not a single string, which originates from reading a file line:

```
proc resolve_signal_path {args} {
set signal_name [lindex $args 0]
puts $signal_name
# Replace [] with ():
set signal_path [string map -nocase {"[" "(" "]" ")"} $signal_name]
return $signal_path
}

# The following "fileline" comes from reading a file so I cannot change it  
# fileline:  abc[0] 2nd 3rd
puts [resolve_signal_path $fileline]
```

How can I pass this 'fileline' variable that is a list of strings, considering it contains [] ?

Comment: I don't know if you have noticed that your second snippet works fine. If `fileline` contains `abc[0] 2nd 3rd` the output is `abc(0) 2nd 3rd`. Perhaps surprisingly, `signal_name` has the value `abc[0] 2nd 3rd`: if you set it using `set signal_name [lindex $args 0 0]` the value becomes just `abc[0]`, and the result `abc(0)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tcl uses `[`…`]` to indicate a command substitution, always, unless you quote it somehow. There are several ways to do the quoting, such as with various backslash sequences (of which `\[`…`\]` is *by far* the simplest), but the best method of all is to put the whole argument in `{`braces`}`, as that simply suppresses all such substitutions (including both backslash and variable substitutions too):

```
puts [resolve_signal_path {abc[0]}]
```

```
puts [resolve_signal_path abc\[0\]]
```

What Tcl *doesn't* do is give you a way to say “opt out of doing substitutions for a particular argument to a command” since it formally doesn't look up the meaning/implementation of the command until after it has already processed the substitutions. In that case, you'd need to use the `subst` to get the selectivity (it'd be the sort of thing you might conceal inside a command, but that's getting rather more complicated):

```
puts [resolve_signal_path [subst -nocommands {$name[0]}]]
```

I don't use that sort of thing very often, to be honest. Using braces and, just occasionally, backslashes mostly works very well.

---

In the updated question, there's a few extra things to consider.

- The `[` and `]` characters are not *actually* special to lists, though Tcl's list-*generating* commands will quote them anyway.
- The `args` formal parameter is special (when it is the last argument) and always contains a list of the (remaining) arguments. This means that if `$fileline` was itself a list, there's two levels of list-ishness to go through.
- When building a list out of substituted pieces, always use the list-generating commands such as `list`, `lrepeat`, `lappend` and so on. When parsing general strings to get lists, `scan`, `regexp` and `split` all either return lists or can if asked right.

So, I'd parse `abc[0] 2nd 3rd` with something like this:

```
set words [regexp -inline -all {\S+} $line]
```

Since that will selectively normalise the spacing and add any quoting required. (In this case, it converts the input to `{abc[0]} 2nd 3rd`.) You'd need to sort out exactly what value corresponds to `$line` — I'm not quite sure from your code — but once the list-conversion is done, you can safely use `lindex` to pick out individual words, whatever characters they once had.

```
set signal_name [lindex $words 0]
# It'll now be exactly “abc[0]”
```

Parsing is in general a matter of understanding what input you *could* have, and making it easy for your code to actually understand that input for what it is. Which sounds simple.

Comment: Thanks Donal, I should have specified the problem better. I have updated the description. My issue is that this argument must be passed as a variable that contains a file line. So I cannot enclose it in {} .